# cron one time higher priority job exception

Tags: cron, jobs, at-job

Is there a way of telling cron that if there is a job with higher priority at the same time it should only execute the higher priority job?

For example:

```
0 12 * * * ~/ring_a_bell.sh # mplayer bell.wav
```

would be standard ringing. But one time only for example on my birthday I don't want it to ring_a_bell.sh but to play_a_birthday_mellody.sh:

```
0 12 21 3 * ~/play_a_birthday_mellody.sh # mplayer birthday.wav
0 12 * * * ~/ring_a_bell.sh # mplayer bell.wav
```

I read that at-job could do this kind of job but the problem is that both `cron` and `at` would execute the job at same time. And that wouldn't sound nice. Is there a way of telling cron to check which one has higher priority and only execute one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, cron is not smart like that.  I can think of one simple way to code your logic in cron, but it's not that nice.

```
59 11 21 3 * ln -s ~/play_a_birthday_mellody.sh ~/script_which_plays_stuff.sh
5  12 21 3 * ln -s ~/ring_a_bell.sh ~/script_which_plays_stuff.sh
0  12 * * * ~/script_which_plays_stuff.sh
```

and as a one-time setup, create `~/script_which_plays_stuff.sh` as a symlink to `~/ring_a_bell.sh`

Anyway, the conventional way of using cron is for running another script inside which you code your logic.